# Streaming Videos from Window Media Server in HTML 5

Tags: streaming

I need to stream videos from window media server in HTML5. But when i researched on Window Media Server, i found that it will stream the .wmv content only. But i need to stream the .wmv content for Iphone/Ipad etc and all the major browsers.

And these browsers need .Mp4,.Ogg,.WebM format in HTML5. I want to use jPlayer. http://www.jplayer.org/

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance